# 3840x1080 (2x 1920x1080) unavailable under Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I miss a feature Nvidia had.

I guess it was called twinview, works like eyefinity for AMD.

I got different Graphiccards:

- GTX 650 Ti,
- GT9600GT and
- GT640(Club3D)

My Driver's version is 310.90 for Win7/64Bit

I can't find it in my Nvidia System Panel. Can I get it to work, or is it deprecated/obsolete?

Comment: which GPU do you have? Which version of drivers do you have installed?

Comment: "*works like eyefinity for AMD*" How does EyeFinity for AMD work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obsolete, it has been succeeded by the windows native ability to use dual monitors within the control panel display settings. Twinview is supported only by Quadro2 and Geforce2. To get an effect similar to eyefinity, you need to use [NVidia surround](http://www.geforce.com/optimize/guides/how-to-correctly-configure-geforce-gtx-680-surround#1), but it is made for 3 monitors.